# C# Devexpress gridcontrol row value to textedit1

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

When you click on any row of the gridcontrol, the value in second column of the clicked row goes to textedit1. Please help me my code as follows and i can not achieve

```
 private void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textEdit1.EditValue = (sender as GridView).GetFocusedRowCellValue("subeadi");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer:[How to dynamically change cell value of a column when another column's cell value changes](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q318724/how-to-dynamically-change-cell-value-of-a-column-when-another-column-s-cell-value-changes)

I suggest that you handle the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event and assign the RepositoryItemTextEdit to these cells in this event handler.

```
private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Check", DBNull.Value);
}

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)    {
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Check" && e.CellValue == DBNull.Value)
        e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemTextEdit1;
}
```

If you are just trying to set a textedit control value on the form then your code is correct. It should work but if you are trying to assign this textedit to grid cell edit control then go through documentation - [How to: Create a Column and Assign an Editor to It](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3061/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Examples/Data-Editing/How-to-Create-a-Column-and-Assign-an-Editor-to-It).

References:
[How to: Set a Cell Value When Another Column Value is Changed](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3039/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Examples/Data-Editing/How-to-Set-a-Cell-Value-When-Another-Column-Value-is-Changed)

Comment: Use the ShownEditor or ShowingEditor event there you can fetch the grid column value and set the editor value